# Add constraint to programmatically created button in swift 1.2

Tags: swift

I am using this code to create my button in swift. It works great except I do not know how to add constraints from code.

```
    let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 50)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

self.view.addSubview(button)
```

I would like to place the button about 50 trailing and 100 from the top. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
    ....
    self.view.addSubview(button)

    button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    let views = ["button": button]

    var constraintHorizontal = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-50-[button]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constraintHorizontal)
    var constraintWertical = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[button]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    view.addConstraints(constraintWertical)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works great for the top constraint however it is setting the leading constraint but i would like to place it 50 to the right edge. Thanks again.

Comment: @johntully change the visual format of horizontal constraint to: "H:[button]-50-|"